# center text relative to element but to the right css

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a span whose background contains an image and some text in div like:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <span style="background: url('path_to_background_image');">My Span</span>
    <span>Some text...</span>
</div>
```

I want the text `Some text...` to always be displayed to the center-right position of the left span (the span that has an image as its background). The text is dynamic, so I want the text to always stay to the right of the left span (centered to the right of it) no matter how big the text grows or how small it shrinks. Is it possible to achieve something like this without JQuery at all (just plain HTML and CSS)?

Please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using only divs, especially if you're always wanting the text to be in a certain spot.  For example if you wanted the two of them together to be in the center and only wanted it to take up a specified size do:

```
  <style>
    #wrapper{margin-left: auto: margin-right: auto: width: 700px;}
    #title{float: left; width: 20%};
    #text{float: left; width: 80%};
  </style>


  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="title">Title</div>
    <div id="text'>...Random amount of Text</div>
  </div>
```

you could play around with the margins etc to get it all perfect.

Comment: The text is to the rght but is NOT centered

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Verber in using divs, although, I just achieved the effect it seems you're looking for with the following code:

```
<style>
.with-background {
position:relative;
height:250px;
width:600px;
background:url(bg-image.jpg);
}

.caption {
position:relative;
left:350;
background:pink;
top:50;
width:200px;
height:100px;
}
</style>
```

..and for the markup:

```
<div class="with-background">
    <div class="caption">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code set a square of text slightly to the right of center (using left:350), and 50 pixels from the top border (using top:50). Since the background image is 600 pixels wide, I set the "left" property of the "caption" class to 350, just a little over half the width of the background image. Modify according to the size of your own background image and you should be good to go.

The "background:pink;" property is just so I can easily see the placement of the div :)

Comment: I don't want `Some Text` to have the same background as the element I want to place it next to

Comment: If you can supply an image that shows what you're trying to accomplish, I can adjust the code to create it. Perhaps I'm not understanding your desired visual effect.